# Confusing TypeScript errors due to hyphen in package name?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, umd

I've built a JavaScript/TypeScript library that I want to work as:

- A global variable when called from either JavaScript and TypeScript
- Accessed via RequireJS when called from either JavaScript and TypeScript
- Has full unit test coverage

This is a UMD packaged using Webpack and deployed as an NPM package here (https://www.npmjs.com/~typed-contract).  If you want the whole source of the branch I'm working on, you can find it here https://github.com/randarp/typed-contract/tree/feature/Issue_5.1.

My problem is that I can't get it to work in all scenarios and my feeling is that the hyphen in the package name (i.e. typed-contract) is the culprit.    Some examples:

- In TypeScript, \Code\TypedContract.Specs\Contract.TypeScript.requireJS.spec.ts

  - If I use *import { contract } from "typed-contract"* then my unit tests fail, but the WebStorm transpiler says it's correct.
  - If I use *import { contract } from "typedcontract"* then my unit tests pass, but the transpiler says Error:(4, 26) TS2306:File 'C:/Projects/TypedContract/Code/typedcontract.d.ts' is not a module.
- I have an external NodeJS application to test this.  In that case:

  - If I use *import {contract} from 'typed-contract'* it works as expected
  - If I use *import {contract} from 'typedcontract'* it won't load the application because it can't find the NPM package under node_modules.

I'm starting to think I need to deprecate this package and start a new one without a hyphen unless somebody can give some clues as to what may be going on because my "programming by permutation" isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a few more failed attempts, I created a new package and deprecated the old one.  It can now be found at:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedcontract.

I just couldn't get it to work in all scenarios with the hyphen, so this seemed like the best long term solution.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm starting to think I need to deprecate this package and start a new one without a hyphen

- I should work with the `-`.
- Don't trust WebStorm too much. TSC should be your single source of truth.

> then my unit tests fail

Perhaps your unit tests are wrong then.